# Problems loading multiple levels with Entity Framework Plus

Tags: entity-framework-plus

I'm having trouble with Entity Framework Plus.  I can't seem to get the loading of multiple levels working.

The following query works fine.  I get the user back with the expected list of addresses.

```
var user = _dataContext.Users
                .Where(u => u.UserName == username)
                .IncludeFilter(u => u.Addresses.Where(a => !a.Deactivated.HasValue))
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

But the following query causes it to fall apart.

```
var user = _dataContext.Users
                .Where(u => u.UserName == username)
                .IncludeFilter(u => u.Addresses.Where(a => !a.Deactivated.HasValue).Select(a => a.AddressType))
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

I get the user back, but now my list of Addresses is empty.

I'm using EF6 and EF+ v1.7.14.0

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Cheers
Craig

Answer (score 2):

Arrgh!  What a dope!  I need to do it in two statements... which makes perfect sense really.  I was selecting out the address type and leaving the address behind.

My query needs to be as follows:

```
var user = _dataContext.Users
                .Where(u => u.UserName == username)
                .IncludeFilter(u => u.Addresses.Where(a => !a.Deactivated.HasValue))
                .IncludeFilter(u => u.Addresses.Where(a => !a.Deactivated.HasValue).Select(a => a.AddressType))
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

Thanks me.  You're a champ!

Comment: Yup, that's, unfortunately, a limitation of the library. The `QueryIncludeOptimized` have the option `QueryIncludeOptimizedManager.AllowIncludeSubPath = true` that do it by itself but it has not been implement yet for `QueryIncludeFilter` yet.